# TypeError: Object of type ResultProxy is not JSON serializable: result in sqlalchemy query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query for 3 fields in a table like this in sqlalchemy:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
        search_form = SearchForm()
        result = dbSession.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM books WHERE (isbn LIKE '%:text%') OR (title LIKE '%:text%') OR (author LIKE '%:text%') LIMIT 10",
            { "text": search_form.searchText.data }
        )
        return jsonify({'result': result})
```

Is my query correct? why would i have this error?

> TypeError: Object of type ResultProxy is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simply error says `result` is not a dictionary. To solve it:

```
jsonify({'result': [dict(row) for row in result]})
```

It will convert each row to a dictionary.

Comment: thanks you. Have one question though. How does python know appropriate column name?

Comment: It doesn't work when in some cases results return no rows. (like in post/put)

Comment: you can add an if condition

Answer (score 1):

I hit this error and it was initially a bit confusing, so it's probably worth further explanation.

The result from an SQLAlchemy SQL query is a list (you can check this with `type(results)`) and it's confusing because usually you'd be able to add a list directly into a dictionary and `jsonify` it.  Further, it looks like a list of tuples, which again would usually be accepted by `jsonify`.

But this is the key: it's actually a list of objects of SQLAlchemy's ResultsProxy type - hence the error.

Thus the error is because it's  a list of a non-jsonify-able type.  However, rather than having to convert it to a dictionary, as per metmirr's answer above, you can also choose to convert it to a list, and then include that list within a dictionary later. Neither approach is right or wrong, but if you're used to getting lists of tuples back from psycopg2, this approach might match your usual workflow better:

```
results = [list(row) for row in result]
result_dict = {'results': results}
return jsonify(results_dict)
```